# MiniMax driven AI takes 5 seconds to perform first move in Android TicTacToe game

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have created a complete tic tac toe game on android with a minimax-driven AI.
I first wrote and ran the code on a console window in NetBeans IDE for simplicity of testing and the code ran fine.
However, when i integrated the code in my android application, it took 5 seconds for the AI to play its **first** move. While the time taken to play other moves was <1 second.
If there would've been any problem in the code then the other moves should've taken some time as well.

I can't find the solution for this problem. Following is my code:

**AI_Move.java:-**

```
class AI_Move {   
private int x;
private int y;
private int score;

public AI_Move() {
}

public AI_Move(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

//getters and setters method.....
    }
```

**AI_Player.java :-**

```
class AI_Player {

    private GameActivity activeGame;

    AI_Player(GameActivity gameActivity) {
        activeGame = gameActivity;
    }

    AI_Move playMove() {
        return getBestMove(PLAYER_AI);
    }

    private AI_Move getBestMove(String player) {          //This is the minimax algorithm function
        String status = activeGame.gameStatus();

        if (status != null) {
            switch (status) {
                case PLAYER_AI:
                    return new AI_Move(10);
                case PLAYER_HUMAN:
                    return new AI_Move(-10);
                case GameActivity.TIE:
                    return new AI_Move(0);
            }
        }

        ArrayList<AI_Move> moves = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                if (activeGame.getValue(i, j).equals(NO_VALUE)) {  //if empty slot is found
                    activeGame.enterValue(i, j, player);    //enter player (X or O)
                    AI_Move temp_move = new AI_Move();

                    if (player.equals(PLAYER_AI)) {
                        temp_move.setScore(getBestMove(PLAYER_HUMAN).getScore());
                        temp_move.setY(i);
                        temp_move.setX(j);
                    } else {
                        temp_move.setScore(getBestMove(PLAYER_AI).getScore());
                        temp_move.setY(i);
                        temp_move.setX(j);
                    }

                    moves.add(temp_move);
                    activeGame.enterValue(i, j, NO_VALUE);
                }

            }
        }

        int bestMove = 0;
        int bestScore;

        if (player.equals(PLAYER_AI)) {
            bestScore = -100;
            for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
                if (moves.get(i).getScore() > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = moves.get(i).getScore();
                    bestMove = i;
                }
            }
        } else if (player.equals(PLAYER_HUMAN)) {
            bestScore = 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
                if (moves.get(i).getScore() < bestScore) {
                    bestScore = moves.get(i).getScore();
                    bestMove = i;
                }
            }
        }
        return moves.get(bestMove);
    }
}
```

**Following are the winning logic containing functions(in GameActivity.java) used in AI_Player.java:-**

```
public String gameStatus() {     //this returns a string indicating the winner or a tie
    ImageButton s1, s2, s3;
    String status;
    isTied = true;

    for (int pos = 0; pos < 3; pos++) {
        s1 = slots[pos][pos];
        s2 = slots[pos][(pos + 1) % 3];
        s3 = slots[pos][(pos + 2) % 3];
        status = check(s1, s2, s3);
        if (status != null && !status.equals(NO_VALUE)) {
            return status;
        }

        s2 = slots[(pos + 1) % 3][pos];
        s3 = slots[(pos + 2) % 3][pos];
        status = check(s1, s2, s3);
        if (status != null && !status.equals(NO_VALUE)) {
            return status;
        }

        if (pos != 1) {

            s1 = slots[2 - pos][0];
            s2 = slots[1][1];
            s3 = slots[pos][2];
            status = check(s1, s2, s3);
            if (status != null && !status.equals(NO_VALUE)) {
                return status;
            }

        }
    }
    return isTied == false ? null : TIE;
}

private String check(ImageButton s1, ImageButton s2, ImageButton s3) {
    if (!s1.getTag().equals(NO_VALUE) && !s2.getTag().equals(NO_VALUE) && !s3.getTag().equals(NO_VALUE)) {    //if all three slots are filled then...
        if (s1.getTag().equals(s2.getTag()) && s2.getTag().equals(s3.getTag())) {   //return winner if the slots are same (contain same tags)
            return s1.getTag().toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {    //if any one slot is empty return NO_VALUE
        isTied = false;
        return NO_VALUE;
    }

}
```

**My "hack" for the problem:-**

However i did find a hack for this problem. I gave the first move (which was taking 5 seconds) to the AI myself through the following code and left the rest of the moves for the algorithm:-

```
Random random = new Random();
    int y = random.nextInt(3);
    int x = random.nextInt(3);;
    fillSlot(slots[y][x], PLAYER_AI);
```

Surprisingly, it worked as desired !

I know this is "dirty work" but i can't think of something else that is why i came here.

Comment: Every call to getBestMove will essentially do an exhaustive search on all the possible moves on the current board. When you start with one of the nine slots already filled, the time it takes to traverse the rest of the moves is roughly 1/9 of what it takes when you start with a blank board.

Comment: @jingx ....and the difference between starting with a blank board and starting with one of the slots filled is drastic.... i mean 5 seconds (with the blank) to <=1 second (with one of the slots filled) ! So there's nothing wrong in using the "hack" right ? :D However, i think the only solution to this problem would be to apply alpha-beta pruning (which i'll have to learn :P)

Comment: At algorithm level one optimization you might try is detect a board that has been evaluated before and don't evaluate it again.

Comment: @jingx i think that's how alpha-beta pruning works right

Comment: Not exactly the same IIUC. Alpha-beta pruning is more about avoiding evaluating situations which are unexplored but we already know are "not worth" evaluating.

Comment: @jingx i’ll try alpha beta pruning since i know how the algorithm works so it’ll be easier for me to implement it and i hope that will solve the problem too...what do you think :)